# Common toolbar and selectors. Do I need to copy the code every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I decided to have a custom toolbar within my navigation controller. To do so, I created this common toolbar class, which every single one of my view controller will add to its navigation item.

```
@implementation MainLeftToolbar

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44)];
    if(self) {
        NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

        // create a standard "add" button
        UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
        bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:bi];

        // create a spacer
        bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        [buttons addObject:bi];

        // create a standard "refresh" button
        bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
        bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:bi];

        // stick the buttons in the toolbar
        [self setItems:buttons animated:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And it is set like this:

```
MainLeftToolbar *leftMenuToolbar = [[MainLeftToolbar alloc]init];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftMenuToolbar];
```

However, I have buttons and one of them is to show the camera (UIPopover). I can't seem to make the camera appear from within the UIToolbar class, therefore, I need to make it appear from the view controller that added that toolbar. I thought about using delegate methods, but this means I will have to copy the code to show the camera **in every single view controller** that has this custom toolbar. Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can think of two options here:

- Create a **base class** for all your viewcontrollers and implement the delegate methods there.
- Create a **property** in you custom MainLeftToolbar that stores the presenting viewController, you set it each time you create the toolbar, that way you can write the common code in your `MainLeftToolbar` class.

Personally, I prefer the **first** approach, this way you can write the toolbar creation code once as well in the init of the base VC, and it also follows the MVC pattern.